# Why is my "open" call only failing sometimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

**Background:**

I'm running my Python program under PyCharm on Windows 10 with three different run configurations.

All seem to run through the bulk of the program fine, doing the logic work without errors.

At the end of the program, there is an attempt to open a file handle, which works on two of the run configurations, but not one, despite the different configurations not affecting the parameters of this call.

**Details:**

This is the piece of code that it is errors in one of the configurations.

```
f = open(global_args[2], "w")
# global_args[2] is always 'new_output.xml'. I've thoroughly checked this
```

The error is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/obfuscated/trunk/PythonXMLGenerator/generate_xml.py", line 270, in <module>
    instance.main()
  File "C:/Projects/obfuscated/trunk/PythonXMLGenerator/generate_xml.py", line 235, in main
    f = open(global_args[2], "w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'new_output.xml'
```

Just for extra information, although I have a feeling it's not relevant, here are two of the run configurations.

```
//Not working
1.0 new_output.xml localdb (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB (2) x x x "0:Upload,1:Modify,2:Delete,3:Download,4:ApplyTemplate,5:RemoveTemplate"
//Working
1.0 new_output.xml mysql localhost (2) obfuscated obfuscated obfuscated "0:Upload,1:Modify,2:Delete,3:Download,4:ApplyTemplate,5:RemoveTemplate"
```

It's maybe worth nothing that I am closing the file handle with f.close() after trying to open it.

**Recap:**

Although the error is happening on a line which shouldn't rely on the context of the wider program, the context nonetheless seems to have an effect and I can't figure out why.

I believe there shouldn't be any issues with write permission in general, as it does work for 2 of the 3 configurations.

Anyone have any thoughts?

P.S. If any more details are needed, I can provide them. Given the confusing nature of this problem, I'm not sure exactly what is necessary.

Comment: Do you have write permissions for the file? Do you always close the file after opening or could there be still active file handles? Are you using Linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: I think I do, as it works for 2/3 of the run configurations. I do close the file `f.close()` and I'm using Windows 10. Will update the question too.

Comment: If you start the program when there is no 'new_output.xml' - Does it still fails?

Comment: My apologies, it was a silly error in retrospect and nothing to do with the code. For this particular run configuration, PyCharm was not setting a working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a code problem as it turns out.

For this particular broken run configuration, PyCharm was not setting a working directory.